# permission user in vue js and laravel passport

Tags: vue.js, laravel-passport

i have role and permission table and I want to check user role and permission in vue-cli with Auth::user()->role or Auth::user()->pemission.

```
Passport::tokensCan([
    'place-orders' => 'Place orders', -----> i want to check this dynamic
    'check-status' => 'Check order status', -----> i want to check this dynamic
]);
```

Comment: What does it have to do with vue-cli? When do you want to check the permission of the user?

Comment: I have  menu and not show to some menu to some user

Comment: I assume that you have a list of menu in the backend, and each of them has their own scope. You can foreach(or map) through the menus and filter out the available menus using `$user->tokenCan('scope')`